# django: how do I query based on GenericForeignKey's fields?

Tags: django, generic-foreign-key

I'm new in using GenericForeignKey, and I couldn't make it to work in a query statement. The tables are roughly like the following:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    issue_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='issue_content_type')
    issue_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    issue = generic.GenericForeignKey('issue_ct', 'issue_id')

class Issue(models.Model):
    scan = models.ForeignKey(Scan)
```

A scan creates one issue, an issue generates some tickets, and I made Issue as a foreign key to Ticket table. Now I have a Scan object, and I want to query for all the tickets that related to this scan. I tried this first:

```
tickets = Tickets.objects.filter(issue__scan=scan_obj)
```

which doesn't work. Then I tried this:

```
issue = Issue.objects.get(scan=scan_obj)
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Issue)
tickets = Tickets.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, issue=issue)
```

Still doesn't work. I need to know how to do these kind of queries in django? Thanks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The `Ticket.issue` field you've defined will help you go from a `Ticket` instance to the `Issue` it's attached to, but it won't let you go backwards. You're close with your second example, but you need to use the `issue_id` field - you can't query on the `GenericForeignKey` (it just helps you retrieve the object when you have a `Ticket` instance). Try this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

issue = Issue.objects.get(scan=scan_obj)
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(
    issue_id=issue.id,
    issue_ct=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(issue).id
    )
```

Comment: @girasquid issue_id is very confusing as it can refer to the field issue_id in question or the id attribute of issue field in the question, can we make them distinguishable?

Answer (score 15):

Filtering across a `GenericForeignKey` can by creating a second model that shares the `db_table` with `Ticket`.  First split up Ticket into an abstract model and concrete model.

```
class TicketBase(models.Model):
    issue_ct = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='issue_content_type')
    issue_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Ticket(TicketBase):
    issue = generic.GenericForeignKey('issue_ct', 'issue_id')
```

Then create a model that also subclasses `TicketBase`.  This subclass will have all the same fields except `issue` which is instead defined as a `ForeignKey`.  Adding a custom `Manager` allows it to be filtered to just a single `ContentType`.

Since this subclass does not need to be synced or migrated it can be created dynamically using `type()`.

```
def subclass_for_content_type(content_type):
    class Meta:
        db_table = Ticket._meta.db_table

    class Manager(models.Manager):
        """ constrain queries to a single content type """
        def get_query_set(self):
            return super(Manager, self).get_query_set().filter(issue_ct=content_type)

    attrs = {
        'related_to': models.ForeignKey(content_type.model_class()),
        '__module__': 'myapp.models',
        'Meta': Meta,
        'objects': Manager()
    }
   return type("Ticket_%s" % content_type.name, (TicketBase,), attrs)
```